# Not able to use input argument function as filter argument (R/dplyr)

Tags: r, function, input, dplyr

I came across following problem when writing a function in R. I wanted to use one of my column names (`id`) as an input argument (`X`) in my function to filter my dataset.

Unfortunately, my function doesn't seem to understand the `X` argument in the filter(). Does someone has any suggestion how I can get this to work?

Thanks

**DATA**

```
library(tidyverse)

df_data <- tibble(
  year = c(2004, 2005, 2006),
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  value = c(10, 12, 1)
)
```

**FUNCTION**

```
FUNCTION <- function(data, X, Y){
    result <- df_data %>%
    filter(X == Y) %>%
    glimpse
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FUNCTION(data = df_data,X = "id", Y = 1)  

Observations: 0
Variables: 3
  $ year  <dbl> 
  $ id    <dbl> 
  $ value <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sym` from `rlang` if the intended input argument for 'X' is a string

```
FUNCTION <- function(data, X, Y){
 data %>%
  filter((!! rlang::sym(X)) == Y) 
}

FUNCTION(data = df_data, X = "id", Y = 1)  
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   year    id value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2004     1    10
```

---

If we are using unquoted value for 'X', convert to quosure and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
FUNCTION <- function(data, X, Y){
 X <- enquo(X)
 data %>%
   filter((!! X) == Y)

   }
```

NOTE: In the OP's post, the 'data' parameter is also different inside the `FUNCTION`

```
FUNCTION(data = df_data, X = id, Y = 1)  
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   year    id value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2004     1    10
```